# "Antidual" of a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

Let X be a banach space.
When does exist a Banach space Y such that X is isometrical isomorph to Y*? When does Y be unique? 
I'm wondering this because I would like to use a weak* topology over X.

If the dimension is finite, then everything is trivial.

If X is reflexive, then Y  must be reflexive (if Y exists). So the claim should be Y=X* 
But even if I prove the claim, this won't help me since weak topology* is equivalent to weak topology under those conditions.

Comment: What you call as antidual is called pre-dual in the literature. There is a huge literature on pre-duals. There is no simple answer to your question.

Comment: I do not understand your last paragraph with reflexive $X$. In particular, the weak topology on reflexive spaces is nice enough, i.e., you do not need a weak-* topology (which, by the way, would always coincide with the weak topology).

Comment: There are also spaces without preduals: $L^1(\Omega)$ with $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: For the existence of an isometric predual, perhaps the paper *A note on dual Banach spaces* Math. Scand. **41** (1977) 325-330 by Sten Kaijser is of interest. For uniqueness, perhaps consult Gilles Godefroy's paper *Existence and uniqueness of isometric preduals: a survey.* In: BorLuh Lin, editor, Banach Space Theory. Proc. of the Iowa Workshop on Banach Space Theory 1987, 131-193. Contemp. Math. **85**, 1989.